# Read and parse a JavaScript file in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, native-file-system-api-js

I need to get some data from a JavaScript or TypeScript file into a Chrome Extension I’m building.

I can use a file picker to get the file’s text contents:

```
const [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
const contents = await file.text();
```

However parsing this text isn’t straight forward. This is as far as I've got. Use a regex to find the object, then parse with `json5` (https://github.com/json5/json5) which makes the input more flexible:

```
const regex = /{([\s\S]*?)}/;
const match = str.match(regex);
if(match && match[1]){
  return JSON5.parse(match[0]);
}
```

It feels brittle using a regex in this way. Is there a better solution?

Comment: It depends on how the object is defined and whether it can be abitrary or there is some telltale. Currently the question is not really answerable, we can just guess. For a truly arbitrary format you'd need to use `acorn` or a similar parser.